# Mahapps Metro Custom IconPack

Tags: c#, wpf, svg, windows-8, mahapps.metro

I am working on a project that utilizes the [Mahapps Metro Library](http://mahapps.com), everything is going smoothly except for one issue. This application requires extensive use of Icons and I need to create some additional Icons.

I have searched high and low for some information on how to define Icons using the [MahApps.Metro.IconPacks](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks) library. I have found all sorts of information on how to use them but nothing on how to define custom Icons.

I downloaded the [MahApps.Metro.IconPacks](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks) library hoping to find an example of how to accomplish this and found that there are several "Auto Generated" files for the different Icon Packs. Obviously there is a tool hiding somewhere but I have no idea where/what it is.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to go about defining a new Icon Pack? I assume that the Icons are drawn as SVG files and the paths are used as the Icons, is this correct? If so is there a particular convention that needs to be used when drawing the Icons? I have both Inkscape and Corel Draw and noticed that Inkscape has a .xaml export that exports a bunch of Canvas and Paths but not sure if this is the right starting point.

Comment: If you are looking for Win8/10 style icons I can thoroughly recommend downloading the free Metro Studio (https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio). I've been using it for years and it provides the XAML source where you can copy/paste the Path data into your own project. Not affiliated to them in any way btw.

Answer (score 1):

To define your custom IconPack, you can just create a resource file, in which you will place the xaml of every icon you are going to create. As you had the chance to see program like Inkscape, Expression Design, or Adobe Illustrator give you the xaml code of what you have create. You just need to copy that in the resource file, and give it a key, so when you will use this resource file in your app you can get the specific icon.

The icon is only the Path part of the code. The Canvas is just a container

Comment: Thank you for the Information, I understand that Icons can be created using the Path of a SVG. What I am after is how to define a custom Mahapps.Metro.IconPack library.

Comment: the only things you can do are explained here : https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks/wiki/Usage. You can create a custom resource file to have everything wrapped in a single file (all the packs from the icon pack + your own resource file). But as far as i know, you can't add own pack to Mahapps inconpack